# Как соотносятся сема, семема и граммема?

Tags: грамматика, терминология

Объясните, пожалуйста, как соотносятся сема, семема и граммема?

Answer (score 1):

Финальная часть составных слов-терминов - ема прибавляется к начальной части слова-термина, который обозначает тот или иной уровень какой-либо исследуемой системы - если языка, то это: фон - звуковой/фонетический, грам(м) - грамматический, лекс - лексический, сем(ант) - семантический, морф - морфологический, текст - текстовый, дискурс - дискурсивный; если идеологии, то это: миф - мифологический, идео - идеологический и т.д. Таким образом получаются слова-термины: фонема, граммема, лексема, семема/семантема, морфема, текстема, дискурсема, идиологема, мифологема и т.д.

-ема - показатель принадлежности к эмическим единицам в оппозиции к этическим, т.е. показатель минимальной далее нечленимой единицы системы содержания, соотнесенной  с точки зрения  уровня системы к аналогичному элементу системы выражения. Таким образом, "емы" (= эмические единицы) представляют собой парадигматические единицы в оппозиции к "аллонам" (= этическим единицам), которые представляют собой синтагматические единицы. Для материальных единиц языка характерна двуплановость/двойственность, т.е. одновременное существование в виде множества вариантов — используемых в речи звуковых отрезков — и в виде абстрактного инварианта — множества всех вариантов.

Для обозначения вариантов единиц существуют так называемые «этические» термины (аллофон, фон; алломорф, морф), для обозначения инвариантов — «эмические» (фонема, морфема, лексема и т. д.). Оба термина принадлежат американскому языковеду К. Л. Пайку. В большинстве направлений лингвистики «этические» и соответствующие им «эмические» единицы относятся к одному уровню языка.

Семема(от греч. semáino — обозначаю)- термин, образованный по аналогии с терминами Фонема, Морфема и обозначающий единицу языкового плана содержания, **которая соотносится с морфемой** (минимальной единицей плана выражения ) как совокупность компонентов её содержания (сем ).

**Таким образом, семема - совокупность сем.**

Иногда **обобщённое понятие семемы расчленяется на два в зависимости от характера выражаемого в морфеме значения: лексема и граммема** (совокупность лексических или грамматических значений).

Существует также **иная интерпретация семемы — как парадигматической единицы, которой соответствует сема в синтагматическом ряду .**

Семы представляют собой элементарные отражения в языке различных сторон и свойств обозначаемых предметов и явлений действительности. Сема является операциональной единицей компонентного анализа и лексико-семантических вариантов слов и установлении их сходства и различия. Она реализуется как компонент семемы — элементарного значения слова (лексико-семантического варианта слова) . **В отличие от семы семема — единица плана содержания более высокого уровня: будучи социально обусловленной, она выступает как содержательная сторона языковой единицы на коммуникативном уровне.**

Структура семемы обнаруживается благодаря сведе́нию содержания
значения к его простейшим составляющим — семам. Семы как конструктивные компоненты значения не одинаковы по своему характеру и иерархическому статусу, так как отражаемые ими объективные свойства предметов и явлений имеют разную значимость для систематизации и различения вне языковых объектов.

https://slovar.cc/enc/bse/2040131.html

Вместо термина «слово» в лексикологии используется термин «лексема» - единица словарного состава языка, взятая в совокупности всех возможных лексических значений и конкретных грамматических форм (термин ввел Александр Матвеевич Пешковский). Слово, реализованное в конкретном контексте с определенным лексическим значением и в одной из грамматических форм, называется лексико-семантическим вариантом (ЛСВ).

**Отдельное значение многозначного слова – семема.**

Каждое слово ( ЛСВ ) представляет собой иерархическую организованную структуру сем (сема – минимальная единица лексического значения, элементарный семантический признак слова: ‘женский пол’, ‘жидкость’, ‘интенсивность’, ’молодой’).